# JS Script called with Ajax stays on cache no matter what

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new at the dev world and my English is not that good (not to say awful!).

I am building an MVC solution on C# and using "GET" and "POST" with JS and jQuery.

I am trying to reload a div without reload the page posting and getting with ajax but the solution only work on the first call.
And the problem it is only with "GET". The "POST" is working just fine!
It seems to stay on cache and won't refresh no matter what.
I already tried "cache: false" and "ajaxsetup cache: false" but nothing works!

This is the div where the scripts is append:

`<div class="datatable datatable-bordered datatable-head-custom" id="tbMetaDadosElemento_lista"></div>`

The button which triggers the event

`<button type="button" onclick="adicionarMetaDado()" id="btnAdicionarMetaDado" class="btn btn-primary font-weight-bold">Inserir</button>`

And here is the js function

```
function adicionarMetaDado() {

            $('#idElemento').val(0)
            $('#idIndiceDoc').val(0)

            var idTipoMetaDado = $('#selMetaDadoTipo :selected').val();
            var descMetaDado = $('#descDadoMetaDado').val();
            var valorDadoMetaDado = $('#valorDadoMetaDado').val();
            var pk = $('#pk').val();
            var tbTarget = $('#tbTarget').val();

            $.ajax({

                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Content("~/APL_Construtor/Elementos/f_Metadados/")",
                data: { valor: valorDadoMetaDado, tbTarget: tbTarget, pk: pk, idTipoMetaDado: idTipoMetaDado, descricao: descMetaDado },
                dataType: "json",

                success: function (data) {

                    $.ajax({
                        cache: false,
                        url: "@Url.Content("~/Areas/APL_Construtor/Scripts/MetaDadosElemento_lista.js?v=7.0.4")",
                        dataType: "script"

                    });

                },

            });

            $('#ModalMetaDados').modal('hide');
        }
```

FYI: I already look at about 100 answers from stack and none of them worked for me.

Comment: That GET request's URL seems to point to a JavaScript file...? It also doesn't contain a success method, so I'm not sure what the goal is here. What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: Exactly to a js file that filled my div with a table. My goal its to reload the div without reload the page in every post

Comment: So what exactly is that script doing? And how do you know it's not executed a second time? And why load a script like that in the first place? If the script doesn't change, why not include it in the page the regular way, then call one of its functions instead?

Comment: I need to populate a table, wich cames in a JS File, every time somebody post a new reocord without reload the entire page. So, everytime a post is request i need to refresh the div with ajax but only works on the First time. Dont refresh on the second time and so on.

Comment: Part of the reason is that your approach doesn't make much sense. Loading a script to refresh a table is not the right approach. You need to 1) load the actual data 2) update your table. Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/gb57x2yv/

Comment: Thanks for your attettion and patience but this wont due for my. I not making my self clear... I Already get the data on the table on the div. The problem stays on every time i need to reload (or refresh) this tabel AFTER my controller returns with new data. It is a page where the user will input the country name and then the states. I need the table (A JS file) with the states to reload everytime a nem state is insert without reload the entire page.

Comment: Look, I'm perfectly aware of what you're trying to do. You are a beginner, I've been doing this for over a decade now. You can keep insisting on your nonsensical approach, which demonstrably *does not work*. Or you can listen to what I'm telling you and fix this. Your choice.

Comment: To refresh table data without leaving the page, you absolutely *do not need* to load a JavaScript file from the server, period. I imagine you have C# code that dumps the table data into your script or whatever, but given that this approach is nonsense, the browser caches your script, thus preventing your approach from working as intended. The proper way to fix this is not to prevent the caching of the script but to do it the right way: write a C# api endpoint that delivers the table data in JSON format and load it from the client-side, then insert it into the table.

Comment: Now I get it: the problem is the aproach with the file! I apply your code adapted to my solution and works like a charm! Thank you again! Cheers!